# An error is issued by gcc relative to parsing type-id in a new expression

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc, c++17, new-operator

This program

```
#include <cstddef>

int main()
{
    const std::size_t N1 = 2;
    const std::size_t N2 = 3;

    int ( **p )[N1] = new ( int ( *[N2] )[N1] );
}
```

[does not compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Yqe0aQNplj0b6YU5) using the compiler C++ gcc HEAD 10.0.0 20190.

The compiler issues error

```
prog.cc: In lambda function:
prog.cc:8:40: error: expected '{' before ')' token
    8 |    int ( **p )[N1] = new ( int ( *[N2] )[N1] );
      |                                        ^
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:8:34: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'main()::<lambda()>')
    8 |    int ( **p )[N1] = new ( int ( *[N2] )[N1] );
prog.cc:8:47: error: expected type-specifier before ';' token
    8 |    int ( **p )[N1] = new ( int ( *[N2] )[N1] );
      |                                               ^
```

However the program compiles using clang HEAD 10.0.0.

Is the pointer type-id specification ambiguous or is it indeed a gcc bug?

**EDIT**: By the way if to remove the outer parentheses like

```
int ( **p )[N1] = new int ( *[N2] )[N1];
```

then clang also issues an error referencing a lambda

```
prog.cc:8:38: error: expected body of lambda expression
   int ( **p )[N1] = new int ( *[N2] )[N1];
                                     ^
```

Comment: "In lambda function" ?

Comment: @max66 I copied the error message as is.

Comment: I see... I'm just surprised. Another "most vexing parse" problem? But I don't understand how can the compiler detect a lambda from your code.

Comment: The g++ error starts from 9.1.0 version, according wandbox; no error before. The funny part is that you have the same error (regarding a lambda function) also compiling C++98.

Comment: The g++ error remain if you use `2` instead `N1`. But disappear if you use `3` instead of `N2`.

Comment: @max66 Change in your comment "If you use 3 instead of N2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is definitely a bug in the newest versions of GCC.  Presumably, GCC is attempting to parse the `( int ( *[N2] )[N1] )` part as a [*new-placement*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#nt:new-placement), i.e., a parenthesized expression list.  Now `int (` is interpreted as a function-style cast, etc.

Per [*new-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#nt:new-expression):

> *new-expression*:
>       `::`<sub>*opt*</sub> `new` *new-placement*<sub>*opt*</sub> *new-type-id* *new-initializer*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>       `::`<sub>*opt*</sub> `new` *new-placement*<sub>*opt*</sub> `(` *type-id* `)` new-initializer<sub>*opt*</sub>

There is no special disambiguation rule regarding *new-placement* vs `(` *type-id* `)`, so the thing should be interpreted as a *type-id* if it cannot be interpreted as an *expression-list*.

---

The **EDIT** part is a syntax error per [[expr.new]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#4):

[ *Note:* Parentheses in a *new-type-id* of a *new-expression* can have surprising effects.
[ *Example:*

```
new int(*[10])();               // error
```

is ill-formed because the binding is

```
(new int) (*[10])();            // error
```

Instead, the explicitly parenthesized version of the `new` operator can be used to create objects of compound types:

```
new (int (*[10])());
```

allocates an array of 10 pointers to functions (taking no argument and returning `int`).
— *end example* ]
— *end note* ]

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but the real answer is:

```
using T = int(*)[N1];
T *p = new T[N2];
```

The declarator-based syntax that C and C++ use is practically impossible to understand once you have multiple declarators. They're hard to write... where do you put the parentheses? What's the order? And they're hard to read... can't go left-to-right, can't go right-to-left, have to spiral inside-out.

Just use aliases. Easy to write, easy to read, easy to parse.

Comment: Thanks. I know this. But it was interesting how to specify the type without using a typedef or an alias declaration.