# What is the reason for the warning: "when type is in parentheses, array cannot have dynamic size"?

Tags: c++, arrays, clang, c++17, new-operator

I posted already a question about a GCC bug relating to dynamic memory allocation of arrays:

[An error is issued by gcc relative to parsing type-id in a new expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57935494/an-error-is-issued-by-gcc-relative-to-parsing-type-id-in-a-new-expression/57935839#57935839)

Now using **Clang HEAD 10.0.0** I am getting the following warning:

```
rog.cc:9:37: warning: when type is in parentheses, array cannot have dynamic size
    int ( **a )[N3] = new ( int ( *[n1] )[N3] ); 
                          ~~        ^~        ~
```

When I run this demonstrative program:

```
#include <cstddef> 

int main() 
{ 
    const size_t N3 = 4; 
    size_t n1 = 2; 

    int ( **a )[N3] = new ( int ( *[n1] )[N3] ); 
}
```

What part of the standard is violated when the non-constant variable `n1` is used?

Comment: It must be the same position that prohibits the use of variable length arrays. This is not valid C++. You might be misunderstanding what the `new` does. In the shown code, it will not allocate both dimensions, but only an array of `int **`s. Therefore, the size of the second dimension is completely irrelevant, since it won't be allocated.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It is not a VLA. For example you may write int ( *a )[N3] = new int[n1][N3];

Comment: At least `using t = int (*)[N3]; int (**a)[N3] = new t[n1];` works.

Comment: @KamilCuk I know that a typedef definition or an alias declaration can be used. But it is interesting the reason of the warning.

Comment: `clang-cl` (in VS2019) and `MSVC` both compile your demo without a warning.

Comment: @Adrian So is it a bug of the clang HEAD 10.0.0?

Comment: Dunno! Maybe you need `language-lawyer`?

Comment: Using `clang` in Embarcadero/Borland gives the same warning as you reported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unparenthesized form uses a *new-type-id*; the parenthesized form uses a *type-id*. Only *new-type-id* allows a dynamic array bound. Plain *type-id* does not. [Compare](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#nt:new-type-id):

```
new-type-id:
    type-specifier-seq new-declarator_opt

new-declarator:
    ptr-operator new-declarator_opt
    noptr-new-declarator

noptr-new-declarator:
    [ expression_opt ] attribute-specifier-seq_opt
    noptr-new-declarator [ constant-expression ] attribute-specifier-seq_opt
```

[with](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.name#nt:type-id)

```
type-id:
    type-specifier-seq abstract-declarator_opt

abstract-declarator:
    ptr-abstract-declarator
    noptr-abstract-declarator_opt parameters-and-qualifiers trailing-return-type
    abstract-pack-declarator

ptr-abstract-declarator:
    noptr-abstract-declarator
    ptr-operator ptr-abstract-declarator_opt

noptr-abstract-declarator:
    noptr-abstract-declarator_opt parameters-and-qualifiers
    noptr-abstract-declarator_opt [ constant-expression_opt ] attribute-specifier-seq_opt
    ( ptr-abstract-declarator )
```

Note that the first production of *noptr-new-declarator* allows the array bound to be any *expression*, while the *noptr-abstract-declarator* production requires the bound to be a *constant-expression*.

Answer (score 3):

the `new` operator (yes, it is an operator, not a function) requires a constructor call template after it, so the first token that can follow the `new` keyword is a type identifier.  The C++ language allows you to specify the type of object to build as some form of cast, by putting a type in parenthesis, but then the type must not be dynamically parametrized (it must be completely known at compilation time).

Just take off the external parenthesis.  As in

```
int ( **a )[N3] = new int ( *[n1] )[N3]; // invalid
```

by the way, in my opinion (i've not tested it) that code needs one more `*` to match the type of `a`:

```
int ( *(*a)[n1] )[N3] = new int ( *[n1] )[N3];  // ERRONEOUS ALSO
```

(as `new` always returns a pointer to the allocated type).  That will assign to `a` a pointer to an array of `n1` pointers (`n1` elements) to arrays of `N3` pointers to `int` (I think you need to divide further your type definition, as probably neither you understand it)

```
#include <cstddef> 

#define N3 (4)

typedef int(*mytype)[N3];

int main() 
{ 
    size_t n1 = 2; 

    mytype *a = new  mytype[n1]; 
}
```

the problem is that C++ doesn't allow to allocate an array of a type defined as

```
type (*);
```

or any combination of that (it requires an identifier after the `*`)